# Powershell - Streamwriter

Tags: powershell, streamwriter

I need to write to many files as quickly as possible but I'm not getting the results I want using Streamwriter the way I'm using. For example, if I write...

```
$File = "c:\somefile"
$Contents = get-content $File
$Contents | set-content $File
```

So read the contents of the file, do nothing, and write it back... The file is exactly the same. However if I write...

```
$File = "c:\somefile"
$Contents = get-content $File
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $File
$stream.WriteLine("$contents")
$stream.close()
```

Then the file looks as though all line breaks have been ignored and is a bit of a mess. What do I need to do to get it write properly? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A Few Points

## `Get-Content` and `Set-Content`

`Get-Content` as you are invoking it reads the file line by line (it doesn't give you the line breaks). So if you do this:

```powershell
$Contents = Get-Content $File
```

Then `$Contents` contains an *array* of strings that represent the lines in the file.

By sending that back out to `Set-Content` (which knows how to handle an array or pipeline of strings) it will write *lines*.

### Arrays in Strings

When you use `"$contents"` the array items will be joined with spaces, not newlines, so when you use `$stream.WriteLine` you are writing a single string with one line break at the end.

### Fixing It

1. Use `Get-Content $File -Raw` to read the whole file at once if it's PowerShell 3+, or use the following to make it into one string yourself.

   ```powershell
   $content = (Get-Content $File) -join "`r`n"
   ```
2. Don't do that, and instead use this:

   ```powershell
   $stream.Write(($content -join "`r`n"))
   ```

Note, I'm using `Write()` and not `WriteLine()` because you don't need to insert an extra line at the end of the file (unless you do, but this could get confusing, might want to add it to the content instead).

Comment: Thank you from a complete novice. That being said, I enjoyed your thorough explanation. Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

`Get-Content` will split the file at the newlines, effectively removing the line breaks. Use the `-Raw` switch to read the file as a single string, keeping the newlines intact:

```
$Contents = get-content $File -Raw
```